# Angular4 Load times are too high with or without lazy loading since they are always downloaded in start

Tags: performance, angular, lazy-loading, production, pageload

Does Angular cache the js files if I do not build the app and only copy all the js, html and css files as is into production? Do they also download them only when needed?

How does angular take care of js files download and the method in which they are instantiated? Seems like ng-cli creates a single minified bundle for the app and there is no option to create  just minified js files which are not bundled into one single bundle file. So seems like they are not lazy loaded and not downloaded on the fly with an http request.

This really takes a toll on the app and the load times are really slow.

Answer (score 0):

The files are cached, yes, but they are not **compiled**. That is what it is making the pages to load slow.

[Follow this guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) to make your code compile [ahead-of-time](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) and your pages should start to load much faster!

Comment: I am already using aot for this code base. Any suggestions after this. How do I get modules downloaded only when needed and cached? Seems like all files are downloaded at the start.

Comment: Enter your website here at [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com) and check what is being downloaded and how much it takes. It may help you find if the problem is on downloading resources or reading them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to speed your load times include using Webpack, Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation, and Lazy Loading. I've found that the most effective way is using [Server-side rendering (aka Angular Universal)](https://medium.com/burak-tasci/angular-4-with-server-side-rendering-aka-angular-universal-f6c228ded8b0).

Comment: I am using aot and lazy loading. Seems like the lazy loading is not lazy loaded. they are downloaded and instantiated when the app instantiates when I do a console.log on the child module.